# Keymap Sublime Text 2 File Type?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

I am working on setting up my own keymaps and was wondering if there is the option to set keys to switch the file type that is being worked on. So for example, if I have a regular plain text file and want it to be a css file, I would have a keymap that would change the document type to css. Possible? If so, please explain to me how you have done this.

Rob

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+P, type "CSS", ENTER should do it too.

Comment: This is the best solution for me as it is easier to use for various files. The below looks interesting but would take me some time to really grasp. I don't see how I can mark this as the answer?

Comment: I will move it as an answer so other people can see it and you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the individual shortcut solution is great, it requires editing the config files and most importantly remembering all the shortcuts you create for each sytax.

In the case of switching file formats it might be more useful to quickly access the required format via the command palette:

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the `Command Palette`
- Type `CSS` to highlight `Set Syntax: CSS` command
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This is great because it provides quick access to all the formats available. Start typing `set syntax...` and all the available formats will be shown.

Answer (score 6):

The keybinding for this would be:

```
{ 
  "keys": ["YOUR_SEQUENCE"], 
  "command": "set_file_type", 
  "args": {"syntax": "Packages/CSS/CSS.tmLanguage"}
}
```

How to discover command names:

- Open the console
- Type `sublime.log_commands(True)`
- Go to an open tab
- Open the command palette and type `Set Syntax: CSS`

The name of the command and it's required arguments should be logged to the console.  From there you just put it in the right JSON syntax.

Comment: Hi @BoudinCode, thanks for your tip , but how can i bound a command like 'command+shift+p, type snippets' do , i know , just list the snippets ? Thanks very much !

Comment: @BoundinCod If you type command+shift+p you can then type snippet and see a list