# Bind shortcut to command palette command?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, key-bindings

I just installed a plugin called CodeSniffer (http://soulbroken.co.uk/code/sublimephpcs), and I want to link one of it's commands from the command palette to a keyboard shortcut because I use it so often.

Is there any easy way to do this? Or will I just need to ask the developer what the name of the command is (in the command palette it is 'PHP CodeSniffer: Clear sniffer marks')?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's actually very easy to find the name of a command but it requires a few steps.

- Open Sublime Text's built-in console (control+`)
- Type in `sublime.log_commands(True)`
- Trigger the command from the command palette

The name of the command will be logged to the console.  Then open your user keybindings and create a new keybinding like this:

```
{ "keys": ["YOUR_SEQUENCE"], "command": "YOUR_COMMAND" }
```

I provided a similar answer here: [Keymap Sublime Text 2 File Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814516/keymap-sublime-text-2-file-type/11822390#11822390)

Comment: This helped me a ton. I was able to bind ctrl+r to the run_apex_script MavensMate command. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: on Ubuntu 18.04 Sublime build 3211 I get an error:
`>>> sublime.log_commans(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log_commans'`

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to crack open the .sublime-commands files.

Let's say you've installed [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) (which you really want to do!) and then open it up in the command palette (⌘⇧p on os x) and install the [Search Stack Overflow](https://github.com/ericmartel/Sublime-Text-2-Stackoverflow-Plugin) package. You'll now have two new commands in the command palette, the "Stackoverflow: Search Selection" and "Stackoverflow: Search from Input" commands.

OK, open the .sublime-commands file for the package. You need to find it first. If you're hardcore you do View > Show Console, and enter `print(sublime.packages_path())`

Otherwise it should be here

- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages
- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages
- Linux: ~/.Sublime Text 2/Packages
- Portable Installation: Sublime Text 2/Data/Packages

and then "Search Stack Overflow/Default.sublime-commands"

This is the file that make the commands show up in the command palette in the first place.

It's another JSON file with entries like these

```
{
    "caption": "Stackoverflow: Search from Input",
    "command": "stackoverflow_search_from_input"
}
```

see, that's the command name right there: **stackoverflow_search_from_input**

Now just open the user key bindings JSON file and add the key binding like @BoundinCode said.

Comment: **See also:** The "installed packages" subdirectory if you do not find it in any of the above-suggested locations.

Comment: and if your package is in `Installed Packages` then you will need to open the archive file (like e.g.: `Terminus.sublime-package`) to be able to navigate to `Default.sublime-commands`