# Sublime text: how to add a key binding to hex_viewer package command

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

I've installed the Hex Viewer package on sublime text 3, to toggle it i use ctrl+shift+p  to open the command palette, then i search for "hex" and select the command of the package to toggle the hex view.

I was wondering how to bind a key to the specific package command, I'm aware of the key bindings configuration file but I don't know what JSON line should I add to call the package command.

This is my first question on stackoverflow, sorry if I did something wrong, have a nice day!

EDIT: This is the github of the package: https://github.com/facelessuser/HexViewer
 It says:

> There are 10 commands available via the command palette or by key-bindings.

This is the one I should like to bind

> Hex Viewer: Toggle Hex View

And this is the string I've tried to paste on the key-bindings JSON file:

```
{"keys":["ctrl+shift+h"] , "command":"Hex Viewer: Toggle Hex View"}
```

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834652/bind-shortcut-to-command-palette-command for a general solution on adding keybindings, not specific to this package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a key binding for the Hex Viewer keymap.

To do this, after installing Hex Viewer via Package Control, navigate to `Package Settings -> Hex Viewer -> Key Bindings - Default` and add the following:

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+h"],
        "command": "hex_viewer"
    }
]
```

To save the file, you need to ensure that the `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\HexViewer` directory exists, assuming this is your package directory.

There's also an example key map available on the GitHub link you mentioned with the other available commands.

**Example.sublime-keymap**

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+h"],
        "command": "hex_viewer"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+i"],
        "command": "hex_show_inspector"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+f"],
        "command": "hex_finder"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+e"],
        "command": "hex_editor"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+x"],
        "command": "hex_writer"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+u"],
        "command": "hex_discard_edits"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+="],
        "command": "hex_checksum",
        "args": {"panel": true}
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+-"],
        "command": "hash_selection"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b","ctrl+shift+g"],
        "command": "hash_eval"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your binding should be

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+h"] , "command":"hex_viewer"}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this to assign a key biding to a plugin

-> Preference -> key - bending - user

then add this

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "the name of plugin." }

]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried something like this but I think sublime doesn't really recognize the command name.

Comment: are you sure about the plugin name?

Comment: Yes, but not sure on what I have to write.