# Sublimetext 3 keybind to a specific command within PackageControl package

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings, package-control

Is there a way to make a keybind to a specific package within package control? For example I'm using the plugin ActualVim and I'd like to be able to make a quick keybind to toggle enable disable it. As it is now I users have to open the package control, type to autocomplete "actualvim..." and disable/enable it that way. Is there a way to key bind to specific commands within package control?

Comment: I think the way to accomplish this is with a macro. You would key-bind to the macro, which would then execute the task. You can look up everything you want about macros in the sublime text docs.

Comment: Ignoring packages is done by adding or removing them from the `ignored_packages` setting in your user preferences; the command you mention is just a convenience. You could define a simple plugin that does this for you and bind a key to that, for example.

Comment: thanks  OdatNurd. i was actually referring to a different plugin called "actualvim", i didn't even realize sublime had a built in vintage mode which does exactly what i wanted. i unignored that module, customized it and uninstalled ActualVim. i can go in and out of vim mode without having to disable anything. thanks for this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind shortcut to command palette command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834652/bind-shortcut-to-command-palette-command)